# Should the markdown documentation mention that only three levels of headers are supported?

Tags: discussion, markdown, help-center

I was re-purposing the markdown preview in SO to check some markdown I was composing, and noticed that `#` level headers were supported to three levels deep only:

---

## Header 1

### Header 2

#### Header 3

Header 4

Header 5

---

Limiting to three makes sense because we're aiming for conciseness in questions and answers.  Should the [help center markdown documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers) note that only three are supported?

Comment: Not saying it's what happened, but the current docs look like something I would have done a long time ago: Writing documentation for some function, showing examples..but oops, this one example breaks functionality. Let's not include that one..

Comment: Do a write up in the new *stack.documentation* site?